# is it possible to deploy OVF on ESX using Python?

Tags: python, virtual-machine, esx

is it possible to deploy OVF on ESX using Python ? 
I looked at PySphere but i couldn't find how to deploy OVF with it, does anyone know ?

thanks,
Eyal.

Comment: Questions of the nature of "Is it possible..." don't tend to do very well here.

Comment: Have you tried it with https://github.com/vmware/pyvmomi?

Comment: no, but I did tried with psphere and pysphere with no luck...

Answer (score 0):

I've found this "OVF tool" 
https://my.vmware.com/group/vmware/details?downloadGroup=OVFTOOL352&productId=353

Deploying OVF is very easy with it 
to use it with python i've just used os.system()

example:

```
os.system('ovftool --acceptAllEulas --net:"OVF-Builder"="VM Network" --diskMode=thin --name='+str(hostname)+' /OVF_Store/ga/'+str(build)+'.ovf vi://root:pass@10.10.10.10')
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible, see this:

https://github.com/vmware/pyvmomi-community-samples/issues/54

You just need to replicate what has been shown in rbvmomi

Answer (score 0):

If you use vSphere 6.0 or newer please check out the vCloud Suite for vSphere. Its a new python SDK released by VMWare that has support for this. Dont let the name fool you into thinking its for vCloud Director because it is not. http://developercenter.vmware.com/web/sdk/60/vcloudsuite-python Specifically check out this: https://vdc-download.vmware.com/vmwb-repository/dcr-public/61f5ad82-3743-4f3b-94fc-2bf1cbcbd8b8/679a5d4d-c48b-477f-b35e-b81c469a656f/client/com.vmware.vcenter.html#module-com.vmware.vcenter.ovf_client